# What was earlier the Earth or the Solar System?

Tags: creation, angels, young-earth-creation, old-earth-creation, earth

My question is concerning the Creation (with literal interpretation, but accepting that the Earth could be millions of years old with the gap theory).

The Bible starts with a statement: "In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth..." At this point there is no reference to the Sun or the other planets.
The next verse show us Tohu and Bohu. Some say that between these two verses there is a gap, so the second verse is actually the picture of the Earth after a doom.

The next verses about the Creation concerning the Earth: light, darkness, vault, water, land, seas, plant, trees (interesting that according to this, plants were created earlier than the Sun). After these, we read that "God made two great lights—the greater light to govern the day and the lesser light to govern the night. He also made the stars". And what about the other planets? These are not mentioned here.

So, according to the scripture it seems to be clear that the Earth was earlier than the Sun. However more interesting question is about, what was earlier the Earth or the other planets (e.g.: Mars, Saturn)?

Later in the book of Job (26,12) [you can find it as well in Isaiah 51,9] there is a mysterious verse: "By his power he churned up the sea; by his wisdom he cut Rahab to pieces." [in Hebrew means shake or smash] Of course, this Rahab is not about the hero of faith. There is an interpretation that here Rahab is about a rebel being or a planet (some say it's the Earth before Adam), which was penetrated (if it's a planet some say, then it could collide with an other smaller planet). Here we can mention that there are theories concerning that the Earth collided with a smaller planet (it could be a doom). Some say that there are angels whose tasks is to protect planets. Anyway the angels are told to be connected to stars as well. What is more, in many culture planets are connected to gods or spiritual beings (Venus-Aphrodite, Mars, Hades-Pluto, Hermes-Mercurius, Kronos-Saturn, Poseidon-Neptune, Zeus-Jupiter). So one of the angels could be the protector of Rahab. The above mentioned things would be references to pre adamic planets.

What do you know about this topic?

Thank you for your answers in advance!

Comment: The answer to this will depend on your interpretation of the creation story. Not all people who identify themselves as Christians believe that the creation story of Genesis 1 - 2 is literally true. Who are you asking?

Comment: I search an answer which is compatible with the Bible.

Comment: All Christians, including those who do not believe the creation story is literal, believe their views are compatible with the Bible. It sounds like you are looking for an answer from those who believe Genesis is literal. Is that right?

Comment: What is a "literal" interpretation? Do you mean that you think it accurately describes history and reality?

Answer (score 3):

Creationists rarely think about the planets of the solar system. As we see at a site that calls itself [YEC Headquarters](http://www.yecheadquarters.org/oec.1.html), science is likely to "redefine the truth", and planets tend to make science the focus of discussion. This [YEC site](https://www.lpl.arizona.edu/~matthewt/yeclaimsbeta.html#rotation) does not tell us what Young Earth Creationists think did happen, but only that scientists are wrong about the origin of the planets. [Answersingenesis](https://answersingenesis.org/evidence-for-creation/six-evidences-of-young-earth/), probably the most widely read YEC site mentions planets only in so far as to claim scientific evidence that the world is only thousands of years old; once again avoiding the issue of just when the planets were created. The implication is that the answer is in the Bible and we need not consider any other explanations.

The Bible's first creation story (Genesis 1:1-2:4a) can be read as covering every aspect of God's creation, with nothing omitted, so there must be a reference to the creation of the planets. It  begins with the earth alone, so just a cold and lonely rock floating aimlessly through space. The planets are lights in the sky above, so the biblical creation of the planets of the solar system (or for that matter the planets of other stars) is to be found in [Genesis 1:14-15](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Genesis-Chapter-1/):

> And God said, Let there be lights in the firmament of the heaven to divide the day from the night; and let them be for signs, and for seasons, and for days, and years: And let them be for lights in the firmament of the heaven to give light upon the earth: and it was so.

Since creationists regard the second creation story (Genesis 2:4b-25) as a retelling of part of the first creation story, we know from the biblical genealogies that the creation of man can only have taken place around 4000 BCE. The planets were created on the fourth day. For Young Earth Creationists and some Old Earth Creationists, these were literal days, so the planets are only around 6000 years old. In this hypothesis, the solar system is at least somewhat younger than the earth.

The gap theory is an attempt to harmonise biblical creation with the science of geology, on the basis that God created the earth (Genesis 1:1) millions, or even billions, of years ago. The gap exists between this initial creation and the events of Genesis 1:2 onwards. However, this does not move the creation of the sun, moon and stars - including the planets- as they are still created on the fourth day. That is resolved by some Old Earth Creationists by assuming that the Hebrew word used here for 'day' actually refers to an indefinite period of time, possibly millions of years. This is an untidy solution, open to many objections, but it provides a semblance of consistency with science. In this hypothesis, the solar system is younger than the earth.

Comment: `Creationists rarely think about the planets of the solar system. As we see at a site that calls itself YEC Headquarters, science is usually something to avoid, and planets tend to make science the focus of discussion.` What nonsense.

Comment: I've never heard of the YEC Headquarters site before so they probably do have a lot of nonsense, but I meant your statement that Creationists don't like to think about planets or that they like to avoid the planets because they make science the focus. If that's true for the YEC Headquarters then you can't generalise from them for the rest of the movement. And that movement unfortunately does talking about science too much! :)

Comment: @curiousdannii OK, as you see, I have reworded my ref to 'YEC Headquarters' to be a more literal report of its views. I don't generalise from them, in fact I think it a bit presumptive of the site's owners to use that title.  Rather than generalise, I gave 3 examples and pointed out that answersingenesis is probably the most widely read YEC site. My purpose was to give a range of YEC views rather than a consensus or an official YEC position (which of course does not exist).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Althogh I'm still not sure that the planets were created on the 4th day, becuse in Genesis 1 when the creation of stars are mentioned in Hebrew the word means stars (which not sure that includes the plants). As planets has no own light. (And God created lights on sky)

Comment: I was also thinking that how is a day without Sun. Interesting questions.

Answer (score 0):

Recognizing that  Genisis does not attempt to explain the creation of the 
physical universe is key. Genesis is only concerned with the unique preparations God made on this planet so that it could support life of all sorts and creating those lives including humans.
The creation of all the universe is only briefly mentioned in the verse you cited Gen 1:1 In the beginning God created the heavens(everything in the universe that is beyond the earths crust) and the earth( the planet earth which was formless and desolate ) Gen 1:2 
Then by the end of the first chapter a brief synopsis on the development of the planet takes place up too and including human life.The bible is a book about humans their rise and Fall and the plan of redemption. It does not attempt to explain how or in what order the various parts of the universe came about.. One brief fact to ponder is the fact that we can see light from the Andromeda Nebula a galaxy that is over  2.5million light years away. That means that it took over2.5million years for the light to reach the observable heavens we see when we look up at night. The universe and planet are very old and the bible comments very little on the specifics. 
Source. https://www.google.com/search?q=andromeda+nebula&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-us&client=safari

Comment: I agree with you that Bible is not for understanding the whole Universe, it's about how can you be redeemed. However I think Bible contains references about pre adamic world as well. For example in the book of Job. Thanks your answer.